# Right limits & Lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $\Phi$ be the class of all fonctions  $\phi$ (let's say from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$) such that:

$f$ has right limits at all points,  i.e. $\lim_{t<s, s \to t} f(s) $ exists

Is any lower semi continuous function a $\Phi $ function?

Comment: Let $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is in the Cantor set and $0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is l.s.c. but it does not have right limit at $0$.

Comment: monotonically increasing function has right (and left) limits at all points and is lower semi-continous

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you develop more?

Comment: I should have said '$1$ otherwise' instead of '$0$ otherwise' .  Characterstic function of any open set is l.s.c..